# What is different ReactiveElasticsearchClient and Reactive Elasticsearch Repository?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-webflux, reactive

I'm trying to get data from elasticsearch reactively using Spring Webflux.
However, When I Use Reactive Elasticsearch client in spring-data-elasticsearch, it seems like it bring asynchronous and non-blocking data via Webclient. Also, I don't know what's the difference between Reactive Elasticsearch Repository offered by spring-data-elasticsearch and Reactive Elasticsearch client.